# Assembly Language - Setting CCR Flags (68000)

Tags: assembly, 68000

I have the following addition and am asked to write what would the values of the CCR flags be. My issue is that I don't know how to find out whether overflow has occurred or not. This is because I don't know whether to treat it as 2's complement or unsigned. Can someone please tell me how would I find this out when I'm facing other problems?

```
$FF + 1:

      1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1
    + 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1
      -----------------
  (1) 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
```

Comment: it would be nice if you specified which processor we're talking about, because almost every computer architecture has its own take on the flags register. MIPS doesn't have one, ARM has the CSPR, x86 has the EFLAGS register. The only architecture I know in which the flags register is called the CCR is the Freescale HCS12, also known as the 68HC12. Can you confirm this is the processor you're using? There is a [68hc12] tag if so.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that, its the 68000.

Answer (score 1):

CCR registers account for both unsigned and signed.  [Wikipedia sums it up nicely.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register)

- **N**: Considers the number signed.  If the most significant bit is 1, then the number is negative, and N is 1.
- **Z**: All bits must be zero for Z to be 1.
- **V**: Always treats the number as signed.  If the operation overflows, contains 1.
- **C**: Always treats the number as unsigned.  If the operation overflows, contains 1.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the Zenexer's:
In your example, the 9th bit goes to carry (that's where the name comes from).

V (overflow) gets set if the highest bit changes "unexpectedly" in the signed point of view: that is if two numbers with msb=0 is added and the msb of the result becomes 1 (as if sum of two positive numbers would give negative result). That's a (signed) overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The best and first place to check is the processor manual, its freely available here: http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf

Specifically, look up section 3-2 and table 3-18 (Integer Unit Condition Code Computations), which lists the boolean equations the processor applies to update the CCR state.